# How to copy multiple files using wild cards in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, wildcard

I'm trying to copy files from one folder to another using multiple source locations and wildcards as a part of filenames, but for some reason `glob.glob` is not working as I have expected (there are only single files per wildcard but version of the snapshot is changing) - getting an error `need string or buffer, list found`.

Part of the python code for that looks like:

```
content=[]
tomcatFiles=[]

def addToContent(srcFile, destFile):
    info={'src': srcFile, 'dest': destFile}
    content.append(info)

def addToTomcatFile(srcFile, destFile):
    info={'src': srcFile, 'dest': destFile}
    tomcatFiles.append(info)

def main():
    baseDir=sys.argv[1]
    intellijProjDir=sys.argv[2]

    deploy_dir=baseDir+'/TransferFiles'
    working_dir=intellijProjDir
    tomcatDir=deploy_dir+"/tomcat"

    addToTomcatFile('/project1/target/project1*.war', '/tomcat/project1.war')
    addToTomcatFile('/project2/target/project2*.war', '/tomcat/project2.war')
    addToTomcatFile('/projectX/target/projectX*.war', '/tomcat/projectX.war')

    for infoObj in tomcatFiles:
        addToContent(infoObj['src'], infoObj['dest'])

    for infoObj in content:
        shutil.copy2(glob.glob(working_dir + infoObj['src']), deploy_dir + infoObj['dest'])
        print('Copied ' + infoObj['dest'])
```

Comment: Please read [mcve]. The minimal code to show this problem is literally one line: `shutil.copy2(glob.glob('foo*'), 'bar')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shutil.copy2` requires a string (or buffer) for its `src` argument, not a list. Since you're sure there will only ever be one match, get the first item returned by `glob.glob`, i.e. `glob.glob(...)[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
for f in glob.glob('foo*'):
    shutil.copy2(f, 'bar')
```